# Why getting error: No matching unique or primary key for this column-list, if I have the same columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

I need to add a Foreign key to my Date_Reserved attribute in the Additional_extra Table, (Maybe because the Date type can't be unique?
I keep getting the next error:

> Error report - ORA-02270: no matching
> unique or primary key for this column-list
> 02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
> *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
> gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
> key constraint in the referenced table.
> *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
> catalog view

For The next Code:

```
ALTER TABLE Additional_Extra
Add(
    CONSTRAINT test_date
        FOREIGN KEY(Date_Reserved)
        REFERENCES Reservation(Date_Reserved)
);
```

This is the part of the task that I need to create. So it is given that Date_Reserved must be FK:

Any Suggestions on what is wrong?
I tried to add FK when creating the Table, however when I find out that just the Date_Reserved FK line is wrong I created without that, but the error is still the same.
I tried from the GUI to add a Foreign key but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_reserved` is part of a composite primary key consisting of many columns; there is no unique or primary key that is solely on the `date_reserved` column.

Your constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Additional_Extra
Add(
    CONSTRAINT test_date
        FOREIGN KEY(Date_Reserved)
        REFERENCES Reservation(Date_Reserved)
);
```

Is trying to refer to a unique constraint that is solely on the `date_reserved` column and that does not exist so the SQL engine (correctly) raises the exception that such a constraint does not exist.

What you need to do is refer to the entire composite key:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Additional_Extra
Add(
    CONSTRAINT test_date
        FOREIGN KEY(Booking_Number, Room_Number, Date_Reserved)
        REFERENCES Reservation(Booking_Number, Room_Number, Date_Reserved)
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i88P8f16)